# get json data from multiple url then push it again in new one

Tags: php

I have 2 api one for posts and comments this is the form of posts:

```
[
{
Iduser: 1,
id: 1,
subject: "subject",
description: "description"
},
{
Iduser: 1,
id: 2,
subject: "subject",
description: "description"
},
{
Iduser: 1,
id: 3,
subject: "subject",
description: "description"
}]
```

and this is the form of comments api:

```
[
{
Idpost: 1,
id: 1,
title: "title",
description: "description"
},
{
Idpost: 1,
id: 2,
title: "title",
description: "description"
},
{
Idpost: 1,
id: 3,
title: "title",
description: "description"
}]
```

so I want to get the user id and push new json api contain posts and their comments in one json object for each user id

this is the code that I start with:

```
<?php 
$json1 = file_get_contents('https://');
$json2 = file_get_contents('https://');

$data1 = json_decode($json1,true);
$data2 = json_decode($json2,true);

$userId = "1";
$user = "";
 foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
   if($value['userId'] == $userId)
   {
       $user = $value['userId'];
echo $user
   }

 }

?>
```

when I echo the $user I get the right number of idUser which their values are 1
but when I tried to push it as array to encode it again like this:

```
foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
   if($value['userId'] == $userId)
   {
       $user = $value['userId'];
   }
    $channels_item[] = array(
            "id" => $user,

            );
 }

echo json_encode($channels_item);
```

I just got more than hundred objects in the json where id=1

how solve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add an ID to the array in the condition, otherwise Foreach will add old data that remained in the variable.

```
 foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
       if($value['userId'] == $userId)
       {
           $user = $value['userId'];

           $channels_item[] = ["id" => $user];
       }

     }

    echo json_encode($channels_item);
```

This should help

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(0);
    $json1 = file_get_contents('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

    $json2 = file_get_contents('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');

    $data1 = json_decode($json1,true);
    $data2 = json_decode($json2,true);

    print_r($data1);

    foreach($data1 as $val){
        foreach($data2 as $value){
            if(empty($val['Iduser'])){break;}
            if($val['Iduser'] === $value['Idpost']){
                $result[] = ["Idpost" => $value['Idpost'], "Iduser" => $val["Iduser"], "title" => $value["title"], "description" => $value["description"], "subject" => $val["subject"], "descriptionjson1" => $val["description"]];
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for trying to help.  Code-only answers are not very helpful.  Please consider adding some description, explanation, and / or some comments to your code to make it useful to future visitors.

Comment: this solve the problem of echo but how can I make user id not repeated and got it only once with all it's posts and comments ? @Sergey B.

Comment: @GNDevs Where does UserID come from? Do you manually set it?
Do you have access to DB?

Comment: I don't have access to database that's why I couldn't solve it with quires and the userID I mean with it Iduser which come from posts api you can see the form of that api above and I didn't set it manually now just for test I did this but I should get them from api and automatically generate one id with value 1 and one id with value 2 and then push with it all posts and comments which belong to this id @Sergey B

Comment: @GNDevs provide a complete example of your API with UserID. Thanks.

Comment: @GNDevs userId and postId It is the same?

Comment: @Sergey B yes it is

Comment: @GNDevs Edited the answer

Comment: I couldn't recognize the output because it's not in json form so I replace the `print_r($data1);` with `echo json_encode($data1);` and replace  `print_r($result);`  with echo `json_encode($result);` but still the output not in json format @Sergey B